# My jquery date picker will not show MVC 5 asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, datepicker

I am trying to display a date picker from this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K5LGL-Bd2lo. I have added the relevant style-sheets but it still will not show up. I have also installed the JQuery.UI Collection. I am eventually wanting to have a start and an end date which I have coded. However I just want to be able to add the date-picker. When I click on the field it is just a text box and no calendar is shown.

_Layout Header & Footer

```
          <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8" />
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
                @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
                @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")


            </head>

                    </footer>
                </div>

                @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
                @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
                @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
            </body>
            </html>
```

PropertiesForm I have an id for StartOfViewing but it still won't link up.

```
   @model OpenPropViewing.ViewModel.NewPropertySellingModel
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "PropertyForm";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

    <h2>Property Form</h2>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Properties"))
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PropertyToSell.StartOfViewing)
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.PropertyToSell.StartOfViewing, new {id = "StartOfViewing"})
        </div>
    }

    @section script
        <script>
            $document.ready(function() {
                $("#StartOfViewing").datepicker();
            });
        </script>

    }
```

I am using these three scripts inside my @section script with script tags:

src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js">

src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"

Comment: you are including jquery multiple times which won't work

Comment: So should I take both of the jquerys out?

Comment: you should have one instance of it

Comment: Should I keep jquery-ui in?

Comment: Even without the extra scripts it still doesn't work

Comment: I inspected the id and it is: PropertyToSell_StartOfViewing
So I change the javascript to:

           $document.ready(function() {
                        $("#PropertyToSell_StartOfViewing").datepicker();
                   });